# signalR: delay when calling OnDisconnected

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

when I refresh the browser page with F5, the OnDisconnected function does not get called straight away. There's a few seconds delay before the function is called, making timestamp values invalids.

```
 public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
```

Why is this happening ? Is it normal behavior in signalR  ?

Comment: "making timestamp values invalid" - you may have worse issues - from the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#onreconnected): "The `OnDisconnected` method doesn't get called in some scenarios"

Comment: these scenarios don't include a page refresh, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. It happens when client is disconnected - when you do refresh page it calls first OnDisconnected() and after OnConnected() cause you load page again.
Also it have task OnReconnected() - but it will be called when you make program reconnect in code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on this a little more. SignalR has a period of time it will wait after a connection has been terminated before it calls OnDisconnected. It defaults to 10 seconds, but you can override this setting in your Global.asax file (example below). Sadly the value requires at least 6 seconds, but I get the reasoning behind it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 110 seconds for a
    // response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
    // make the client reconnect.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);
    
    // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
    // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
    **GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);**
    
    // For transports other than long polling, send a keepalive packet every
    // 10 seconds. 
    // This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

The way I'm handling this, is in the OnConnected function, I store and look for another piece of unique identification for the client (in my case the IP Address), and if I find that client, go ahead and remove that older connection from my custom session collection.